# Finding total variance based on conditional variances

Tags: variance, conditional-probability, conditional-expectation

I'd like to ask a question I came upon at work. I will substitute the proprietary names with variables for the sake of prudence.

Suppose I am working in a plant and have many (i.e., 10) moisture values for each of three mixtures. The mixtures are denoted as $Z_1, Z_2,$ and $Z_3$. Each mixture is comprised evenly of two ingredients; one that is ingredient $Y$, and the other $x_1, x_2,$ and $x_3$ respectively. So, for example, mixture $Z_3$ has ingredients $Y$ and $x_3$. The two ingredients in any given mixture are actually the same ingredient- differing only in their source (mixture $Y$ comes from one company, and the other $3$ come from another company).

I need to deduce the variability of $Y$.

So far, this is what I've been thinking:

- I might be able to use conditional variance to describe the variance of the moisture values I already have; for example, I can say that the variance of $Z_1$ is Var($Y|x_1$). My guess is that to find Var($Y$), I need to take into consideration Var($Y|x_1$), Var($Y|x_2$), and Var($Y|x_3$).
- The Law of Total Variance says that for random variables $X,Y$, $$\text{Var}(Y)=\text{E[Var(}Y|X)]+\text{Var(E}[Y|X]).$$

However, in my case, I have $X=x_1,x_2,x_3$; how can I (if at all) use the Law of Total Variance to compute the Var($Y$)?

Further info:

- I can't say much about the distribution for the moisture values beside that they're non-normal
- I am essentially interested in the intrinsic variability of Y (the ingredient itself)